# Laptop CPU temperatures: 65°C in idle, 100+°C in heavy load

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, temperature, overheating

The laptop is a 4 years old  Asus N56VZ, ambient temperature is around 25°C.

I've already unmounted the laptop, cleared the (not much) dust and changed the original thermal paste with Arctic MX-4, but the temperatures won't drop. I'm on Windows 10, I've also checked the temperatures with a clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and they're pretty much the same. The situation seems to be pretty critical given that if I start a system scan in Bitdefender the computer will turn off automatically after ~20 minutes because of the activation of the thermal protection.

I specify that the CPU used to have normal temperatures, around 40-45°C in idle and 80°C in heavy load, before that this problem started. If it is not the OS/loads, the dust or the thermal paste causing these temperatures, what can it be?

Comment: Do you mean Celsius or F? 80 degrees C is 176 degrees F. Your computer should not be getting that hot. Not only is bad for the computer, but it could be potentially harmful to your health or even fatal.

Comment: Celsius as said in the post, but I forgot to specify I'm talking about the CPU's temperatures. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Do you hear the fans kick on when it has a load or is it quiet?

Comment: @JCTechie yes the fan seems to work well, it stays ~2000RPM in idle and ~3500RPM under charge. It surely goes even higher under extreme charge but I haven't measured its speed in this situation.

Comment: Well I suggest taking your computer to a repair shop. I would actually have to see the pc to fix it. It sounds like a hardware problem which is hard to fix over the internet.

Comment: As all else has failed to soccer your problem can you update the BIOS?

Comment: @DDay I already have the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought: If you changed the thermal paste and removed the heat sink yourself, make sure you screwed it back in the correct order.

Each screw is numbered to have the heat sink aligned properly with your cpu/gpu. I have made this mistake in the past and it really hit the temperature quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

My 8 year old laptop was also getting very hot, i opened it and cleaned it up(or so i thought) many times - didn't work. But then last time I opened it up completely(like remove the whole board), opened the fan screws removed the cover an behold there was a half inch thick dust clot on the fan outlet. Now it's running suppper nice.

See the dust on the fan outlet.
[image]

Look how how much it's.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*

> ...lower your maximum power of CPU on 70% in power options...

*

Yes... this adjustment really works... although cranking down to 70% seems a bit drastic.

Start with 90% That should do just fine and this should stop your laptop from switching off because of excess heat.

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options...

Change plan settings...
Change Advanced Power Settings...
Processor power management...
Maximum processor state...

Choose 90% for both options and click OK

Answer (score -2):

Take a thermometer and measure the outgoing air of the laptop, if it's different than the temperature readings in your software/BIOS, then it's possible that the temperature sensors on the motherboard are bad.  If they are bad, you can try and set your BIOS so that it doesn't shutdown the system for another 20°C, if you do that though, I highly recommend keeping an external thermometer on the laptop's air outtake so that you can manually keep an eye on it.

Comment: It will be lower unless the CPU is exposed

Answer (score -3):

to cool your cpu
install NOTEBOOK FANCONTROLL, with this you can force your fan to 100%,
next thing, is more effective, lower your maximum power of CPU on 70% in power options,
try it
worked for me, my CPU is min 38°C, max 78°C
sorry for bad eng.
hope it helps

Comment: You are throttling the CPU by reducing the CPU power.